# Отсутствует оператор, соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: c++, list, список, stl

Я новичок в программировании на С++, у меня вылезла ошибка, не понимаю почему. Вот код:

Ошибка на 35 и 37 строчках
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Потому что к списку `list` действительно нельзя обращаться "по номеру", как к вектору — с индексом в квадратных скобках. Вместо этого следует использовать итераторы.

Ну, или векторы вместо списков.

А еще — здесь категорически не принято задавать вопросы в картинках. Куда лучше (и проще, кстати!) дать текст.